# How to Unlock "Locked" files in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I accidentally ended up with all project files being locked in VS 2013.
Now, when I edit resource file and rebuild I get

`error MSB6006      exited with code 1`

[image]

**Potential reasons why the files are locked:**

1. editing .rc file manually (removing long comments ....)
2. adding Setup project

Comment: The icon indicates that you have added your project into source control by git.Also, what is the whole error?(you can enter `Tools`-->`Options`--->`Projects and Solutions`-->`Build and Run`-->set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Detailed`) and then build again to get the detailed build log. Actually, this icon means that your project has been locked in Git source control. It does not mean that your project is locked for other reasons, so please share the specific error with us.

Comment: Close VS Instance, enter your solution folder, delete `.git` hidden folder and then restart your project-->Build, did the issue happen again?

Comment: Thank you. Files are unlocked after deleting .git file.  But i still can't edit the resource file.

Comment: I am getting "fatal error RC1022: expected '#endif'" when i just change control name

Comment: The complete  error message is :  Done building target "ResourceCompile" in project "ProjectName.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed, #endif was missing a resource file. Works fine now.

Comment: Glad to know that you have solved the issue with our help. I have added an answer for you and you can check it. Anyway, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, if you want to unlock the resource files from git source control, you could modify `.gitignore` file in the solution folder, add any files you want to exclude from source control. The file saves the files which will exclude from git. Or just run git command:

```
git reset -- <file>
git rm --cached <file>
```

Please check this document about [ignoring file changes with Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/ignore-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#permanently-stop-tracking-a-file).

**Also**, you can also delete `.git` hidden folder。

> I am getting "fatal error RC1022: expected '#endif'" when i just
> change control name

You should note this info:[Resource Compiler Fatal Error RC1022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/resource-compiler-fatal-error-rc1022?view=vs-2019).

```
An #if, #ifdef, or #ifndef directive was not terminated with an #endif directive.

Make sure that there is an #if, #ifdef, or #ifndef statement in effect before this statement.
```

**Please** note that you should use `#if`, `#ifdef`, or `#ifndef` which ends with `#endif`.